# System Settings won't Open / Boot Up Issue (16.04)

Tags: boot, suspend, system-settings

I tried opening my System settings today (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS) and nothing happened, other than the mouse turning into a busy signal for about 10 seconds. The same thing happened when I tried opening it from the search bar. Then I tried launching it from the terminal. It returned the following code:

```
unity-panel-service stop/waiting
unity 7 stop/waiting 
unity-panel-service start running process 16752
compiz (core)-Info: loading plugin: core
compiz (core)-Info: starting plugin: core
compiz (core)- Loading plugin: control
compiz (core)- Error: Failed to load plugin: control
compiz (core)- Info: Loading plugin: center
compiz (core)- Error: Failed to load plugin: center
```

Then everything apart from my desktop and terminal window disappeared, including all the menu bars and launcher. I was forced into a hard reset. I had to copy down the code you see above, and enter it in manually here.

I just tried removing it through the terminal so I could reinstall. It didn't work, and returned the following code:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree      
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package control
E: Unable to locate package center
```

So now I don't know what to do? I have no access to my system settings.

Also, I have been unable to boot up my system for months now. I made another question about it, and any and all suggestions and answers I could find through that question did not work. My system gets to the black screen and prints "Loading Operating System". It remains there indefinitely. I have to boot up into Recovery Mode (via cntrl-alt-dlt), and it works fine from there.

In order to avoid this, I put my computer into suspend 95% of the time. Will leaving my computer in suspend all the time damage my hardware in any way?

Comment: Could be hardware related problems, bad RAM, faulty HDD, etc.

Comment: How do I test for that?